# Excel: Wildcard search in row and return all matching values

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to figure out a formula that helps me search a row for a wildcard text (e.g., w*) and returns all matching values (in one or several cells).

What I have looks something like this:
[image: Data example]

What I would like the formula to do is this:
[image: Results example 1]

Or that:
[image: Results example 2]

What I've found so far are solutions for searching columns (and often without wildcard options) but I can't make it work for searching rows. Can anyone help with that?

Comment: please post the formula you are using. As far as I am aware, Excel formula work on a range, and it doesn't matter if the range is columns or rows or both. Hlookup and Vlookup are different so they have two variation.

Comment: @VSRawat Unfortunately, I do not have a formula. That's what I'm looking for. Vlookup and variants thereof only find the first matching result. But I would like to get all of them.

Comment: Does this need to be scaleable, or just handle a fixed number of value columns?  Your 2nd result looks like a separate column for each match.  In that case, must the values be consolidated to the left, or can there be empty cells for where there were no matches?  If that is a possibility, you just need a result table the size of the data, and each cell checks the corresponding cell.

Comment: @fixer1234 I have dozens if not hundreds of "Value" cells. And a maximum of 6 "ws" for each "Person". Generating a Vlookup for each of the "Value" columns would make things extremly messy.

Comment: Approximately how many columns will you be checking. Also is the real check based upon what the first letter is as per your example "w" or possibly other multiple character combinations such as checking for only "wx"* . It appears only the first letter is looked at really. If the column qty is large a macro may make more sense. Other wise  this checks for the letter in A1  
 =IF(LEFT(C2,1)=A1,C2,"")&IF(LEFT(D2,1)=A1," "&D2,"")&IF(LEFT(E2,1)=A1," "&E2,"")&IF(LEFT(F2,1)=A1," "&F2,"")&IF(LEFT(G2,1)=A1," "&G2,"")&IF(LEFT(H2,1)=A1," "&H2,"")&IF(LEFT(I2,1)=A1," "&I2,"")&IF(LEFT(J2,1)=A1," "&J2,"")

Comment: @datatoo,, post the Formula as Answer instead as comments.

Answer (score 1):

I can give you a kludge solution that works.  I'm sure there are better solutions, but I normally use LO Calc, and it behaves very differently, and the only Excel I had ready access to was Excel online, and it doesn't do array formulas.

This solution is based on your comment that you have dozens or hundreds of value columns and a maximum of six "w" values.  It returns six "w" values for each row, some or all of which can be blank if there are fewer matches.  It uses helper columns for intermediate values, which you can hide or stick in a convenient location.  Here's an example with six value columns, and I'll explain how to scale it to your data.

[image]

Your sample data, plus a 6th column I added, are in columns B:G (plus the persons in column A).  For your own data use the appropriate column range, just observe the dollar signs for absolute addressing.  My helper columns are in I:N, and the results are in P:U.

There are two formulas used in the helper columns, one for the first column and one for subsequent columns.  The helper columns identify the locations of the matches.  Similarly, there are two formulas for the results columns, first and subsequent.  Enter those four formulas and copy as needed.

**1st helper column**

The formula in I2 (copy down as needed):

```
=IFERROR(MATCH("w*",$B2:$G2,0),0)
```

This finds the first wildcard match, or returns `0` if none for the row.

**Subsequent helper columns** (2 through 6)

The formula in I3 (copy to the right and down):

```
=IF(SUM($I2:I2)=COLUMN($G2)-COLUMN($A2),0,IFERROR(MATCH("w*",OFFSET($B2:$G2,0,SUM($I2:I2)),0),0))
```

The meat of the formula works the same way as the first column, but instead of looking at the entire row, it looks to the right of the location of the last match.  The first IF test checks for the last match being the last value column so it doesn't try to match in non-existent columns.  For your actual data, replace COLUMN($G2) with the last value column, and COLUMN($A2) with the column before the first value column.

**First result column**

The formula in P2 (copy down as needed):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B2:$G2,1,$I2),"")
```

This retrieves the value from the column identified by the first match, or displays a blank if there was none.

**Subsequent result columns** (2 through 6)

The formula in Q2 (copy to the right and down):

```
=IF(J2=0,"",IFERROR(INDEX($B2:$G2,1,SUM($I2:J2)),""))
```

Again, this works the same is the first, but adds up the previous match offsets to find the location.  It also checks whether there was no match, in which case it displays a blank.

Comment: It's complicated but working ,,, ☺

Comment: @RajeshS, are you going to tackle this one?  It seems like a simpler solution ought to be possible with an array formula and small, but I couldn't get LO Calc to cooperate with wildcards and Office Online doesn't do array formulas.

Comment: my formula sometimes fails to get value due to wild card otherwise I've almost solved it ,,☺

Comment: now check my post, finally I've cracked the issue with some trick or with as alternative.

Answer (score 1):

@Sherly, this one is the improved answer which searches the `W's` in Rows instead of Columns as I've shown earlier.

[image]

**Result:**

Write this Array (CSE) formula in `H141`, finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**, Fill Down then Right.

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($B141:$G141, SMALL(IF(LEFT($B141:$G141,1)="w", MATCH(COLUMN($B141:$G141), COLUMN($B141:$G141)), ""),COLUMNS($A$1:A1))),"")}
```

*Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*

Answer (score 0):

*@Sherly,, I would like to suggest an Array (CSE) Formula, will extract all values starts with W from Specified range.*

[image]

**Note,** since Wildcard is not working with Numbers and the data around the range has `W` followed by Numbers so that, I've used a trick to solve the issue, which is,

`(IF(LEFT(B$141:B$150,1)=B$153`

where **LEFT** pulls the `1st Character` which matches with `B153` has **w**, and this only supports the Formula to pull all `Ws`Followed by numbers.

**How it works:**

- Fill `B153 to G153` with **w** (Which is Helper 
  Row).
- Write this Formula in Cell B154, finish with 
  **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**, Fill Down then Right.

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX(B$141:B$150, SMALL(IF(LEFT(B$141:B$150,1)=B$153, MATCH(ROW(B$141:B$150), ROW(B$141:B$150)), ""),ROWS($A$1:A1))),"")}
  ```

**Edited:**

*To search & extract **W's** in `Row` you need to write this Formula in `B160` (fill Right then Down):*

`=IF(LEFT(B141:G141,1)="w",LEFT(B141:G141,1)&RIGHT(B141:G141,LEN(B141:G141)-2+1),"")`

[image]

- It's not an intelligent Formula but ultimately it works.
- *Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*

Comment: You're close.  It took me a minute to figure out why your results didn't match.  You're summarizing columns while the OP wants to summarize rows.  But that should be an easy fix.  BTW, since the OP is only interested in "w", you don't really need the helper row, you could just hard code it in the formula.

Comment: @fixer1234, since my Formula checks column after column left to right that's the reason I've used Helper Row Cell reference is B$141:B$150 as moves right then is C$114:C$150,,, which helps the Formula to move next Column to search the string.

Comment: @fixer1234, using helper row enhances the scope which could be multiple search in Columns .

Comment: The main issue is that it should do rows instead of columns.  But re: helper column, wouldn't you get the same result with `IF(LEFT(B$141:B$150,1)="w"...`?

Comment: @fixer1234, yes u are write that's one major reason. And the prime is Wildcard doesn't supports Numbers therefore `= B$153 & "*" ` is not working otherwise search in Row is possible!

Comment: But doesn't LEFT solve that?  And should rows work the same way as columns (just specify row ranges instead of column ranges)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89588/discussion-between-fixer1234-and-rajesh-s).